# AWS APIGateway - Display resources (endpoints) for HTTP API from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

When I create REST API via APIGateway, I have a beautiful dashboard to allows me to see different endpoints:

[image]

Problem:
When I create HTTP API via APIGateway, I can't see my different endpoints like below:

[image]

My need and my goal:
I want to document my API resources in order to generate a swagger and to be able to make requests directly in the swagger.

I don't want to use S3 solution.

I used Cloudfront to make a required authentication before accessing swagger.

Thank's in advance :)

EDIT: @eli6, the problem is:
When I click on Routes, I have only this:
[image]

Comment: If you only see $default when clicking on Routes, that means that you don't have any specific Route configured, only the "default" route that catches all requests to the API. Could it be that you haven't defined any routes yet? 

If you do have different routes that you can call though this API, they are probably defined directly in the backend code (in a lambda function for example), and the HTTP API just passes all requests to that function. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I use APIGateway V2 and $default intercepts all endpoints. I wanted to have access to the endpoints so I could document them and generate a clean swagger.

Comment: If API Gateway doesn't know about the endpoints it can't generate any view or definition of them. You will have to go look at where the endpoints are defined and try to get the definition from there (most likely your code then..). That's not a difference between REST API and HTTP API. If you define your endpoints in the API they will show up there, doesn't matter what kind of API, and if you do a proxy integration where you just pass the requests on through a single endpoint (default/root endpoint) the endpoints won't be visible and API Gateway doesn't even know what the endpoints are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the menu to the left on the HTTP API view, you can click on "Routes" to see the different endpoints, or on "Export" to export their definition in the [OpenAPI 3](https://swagger.io/specification/) format. OpenAPI 3 can be imported and used with the Swagger tools.

[image]

Comment: Thank's @eli6 Unfortunately it doesn't meet my needs.
My goal is to generate a swagger with editing the documentation of the methods to have a beautiful swagger documented